# How do I use a custom testrunner for just a particular test?

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [django unit tests without a db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917587/django-unit-tests-without-a-db)

I have a module that I want to  test, but I don't want to create the test database for it. (It doesn't use the database at all)

Is there anyway to specify a particular testrunner for just that test?

Comment: assuming this refers to Django, from the tag. can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do?  do you want to run its tests completely separately from the django tests?  is the module inside an app?