# Using django-discover-runner without database

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm trying to use django-discover-runner to test my app. It's basically a WebService frontend, so it doesn't include a database, and, apparently, django-discover-runner doesn't like that.

Looking in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917587/django-unit-tests-without-a-db), I've seen that with plain Django, I should inherit from `DjangoTestSuiteRunner` and set `settings.TEST_RUNNER`. It works fine. But django-discover-runner uses its own `discover_runner.DiscoverRunner` class, so I tried this:

```
from discover_runner import DiscoverRunner

class DBLessTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def setup_databases(self):
        pass

    def teardown_databases(self, *args):
        pass
```

But it doesn't work. I get this error message:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Any idea how to get django-discover-runner working without a DataBase?

Answer (score 3):

In Django 1.6 the standard Django TestCase inherits from TransactionTestCase which attempts to access the database.

To fix the problem in your test class inherit from SimpleTestCase rather then TestCase:

```
from django.test import SimpleTestCase

class TestViews(SimpleTestCase):
    ...
```

You should now be able to run your tests with out setting up the database.