# why django SimpleTestCase create test database

Tags: django, database, performance, unit-testing

as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21012054/846634) question and in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#simpletestcase), when using SimpleTestCase in unit testing, django should not create test database (which takes too long).

Inside one of my applications which is called "search, I have some unit test inherited from SimpleTestCase. this is tests.py inside search application:

```
class TokenizerTestCase(SimpleTestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        self.assertItemsEqual(1, 1)
```

When I call `python manage.py test search.tests.TokenizerTestCase` it takes too long to build default database. does anybody know why it is creating database for test?

Comment: What does the startup look like? What text does Django display when you're running the tests?

Comment: @SimeonVisser at first line it writes:

Creating test database for alias 'default'...

then it prints some warnings about migrations.

Answer (score 3):

By default `SimpleTestCase` creates a test database. You can extend the class for your own functionality. If you do not want to create a database of your own in each and every setup setup your own test environment extending the classes.

Override the _pre_setup and _post_teardown methods. For more information read the source code for `TransactionTestCase` to see how it creates the test database structure.

Read the source code [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/django/django/master/django/test/testcases.py)