# How to avoid creating test database for testing in django?

Tags: django, django-tests

I have written some test cases for my project when I run these test cases, it creates test database for alias 'default' every time, after giving message then destroy database. I am concern only with **message**, So How to avoid creating test database, because it takes lots of time.

```
username$ ./manage.py test
...............
Some message, I Want only this message 
...............
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917587/django-unit-tests-without-a-db

Comment: Try using `SimpleTestCase` in your tests.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
python manage.py test -k
```

In Django 1.8, you can use -k command.

> New in Django 1.8: You can prevent the test databases from being
>   destroyed by adding the --keepdb flag to the test command. This will
>   preserve the test database between runs. If the database does not
>   exist, it will first be created. Any migrations will also be applied
>   in order to keep it up to date.

You can read this for more details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: I get it, so, in this case, i think this solution maybe can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917587/django-unit-tests-without-a-db.

You have tried it?

Answer (score 9):

Well, it's just a comment, not an answer yet - so I'll repeat the comment of Rahul Gupta:

Just subclass from `SimpleTestCase` instead of `TestCase`, see [Django Testing Tools Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#simpletestcase).