# Why is Django test throwing an error complaining about a column size that is incorrect when I try to run tests?

Tags: python, mysql, django, testing, typeerror

I have an old project that I'm resurrecting that was built with Python 2. I'm getting it going with a more current version of Python and Django (v3.9 and v4.1.2 respectively). I have the app basically up and running and I just tried to get the automated testing going. But I'm getting this error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1074, "Column length too big for column 'body' (max = 16383); use BLOB or TEXT instead")`

Unfortunately, I have the 'body' column in multiple objects in my models.py, AND each of them is defined as a TextField (e.g. `body = models.TextField()`).

I'm not sure how to post the offending code since the error doesn't specify the exact object. My test is simple as I'm just trying to get testing going:

```
from django.test import TestCase
class Test_Countries(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def test_basicCompare(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

Before running the test (`python manage.py test IFSServices/tests`), I've ensured that makemigrations and migrate have succeeded.

Any help that anybody could provide to help (incl how to ask a more useful question) would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE
I stumbled across this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37150997/1524875
If I implement the code to disable migrations per that post, the problem I reported here goes away and the tests behave as expected.

Comment: What database are you using (and what version?)

Comment: 8.0.31 (MySQL Community Server - GPL) on OSX 12.6 x86_64

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953538/mysql-column-size-limit (See also self-answer in the question itself, about `SQL_MODE` being set to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`)

Comment: I don't think so. When I ran ```SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';``` it returned only ```NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO```. But thanks.