# How to write tests for django multi tenant applications?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, multi-tenant

I have multi-tenant applications in django with postgresql schemas. I tried to write test code inside a tenant folder "t002" as:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from path.customers.models import Client
# TestClass to test tenant setup
class TestTenantSetup(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Client.objects.create(
            name='t002',
            schema_name='t002', 
            domain_url='t002.cmpny.com'
            )

    def test_tenant_exists(self):
        client = Client.objects.get(name='t002')
        self.assertEquals(client.schema_name, "t002")
```

But when I ran the test with **python manage.py test path/t002/tests** it was creating a test database for my actual database. So let's say I would follow this SO answer ([django unit tests without a db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917587/django-unit-tests-without-a-db)) and avoid creating database, but I am not sure if I'm following the right path to test a multi-tenant django project. When I looked into the **django-tenant-schemas** docs (https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test.html) I couldn't get my hands on it easily. Can anybody tell how start doing test for django multi-tenant applications ? And please do review the above code too whether it is right or wrong.

Specs - python==2.7, django==1.11, postgres==9.6

Comment: Could you please add additional information to your question.
It seems you don't want a test database to be created. What would you like instead? Let the test use the real data base and create new rows there?

Comment: Yes that part, I already checked an SO answer, but basically how to start unittest for a django multi-tenant application is my question. Above snippet is the one I had tried to test for tenant setup, is that the right way ? or if I should follow some other ? I mainly ask for multi-tenancy @gelonida

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what soft of isolation do you use in your multi-tenant application.

If you use different database settings or any other settings you can override their test version in you tests with [@django.test.override_settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings).

For example:

```
from django.test import override_settings

@override_settings(DATABASES=<...>)  # you can also load and/or override other settings for a specific application
class TestTenantSetup(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Client.objects.create(
            name='t002',
            schema_name='t002', 
            domain_url='t002.cmpny.com'
            )

    def test_tenant_exists(self):
        client = Client.objects.get(name='t002')
        self.assertEquals(client.schema_name, "t002")
```

Comment: Actually I mentioned that there's a solution for overriding DB creation. But what I asked for is, whether we should proceed like normal Django unit testing or is there some other way to do testing for multi-tenant system ?

Comment: Yes, treat it as a normal Django app. In general it's better to keep the tests simple and isolated. If you need to test some interactions between the apps inside you Django app then create a test settings. it should be close to what you use in reality but doesn't require dependencies that are out of the scope of what you are testing.